# Is there any drawback to breathing deeply all the time?

Tags: breathing

Normal, relaxed breathing (eupnea) uses the external intercostal muscles. Diaphragmatic breathing (deep breathing) is more efficient because it balances the ventilation/perfusion ratio across the lungs by ventilating the lower half of the lungs more (as far as I understand), allowing for more efficient gas exchange. It also has various health benefits. The respiratory center in our brain controls breathing to regulate carbon dioxide and oxygen levels in the blood. Is there any drawback to breathing slowly but deeply all the time, or is it just that humans are inefficient?

Comment: Why question on how something didn't evolve are pointless. Most likely it simply didn't happen. There is no reasoning in evolution, it happens by chance.

Comment: I edited my question to clarify the real meaning of what I was trying to say.

Comment: What does it mean to be "more efficient"? What is the survival/reproductive benefit of that efficiency?

Comment: Many online sources claim that it is "more efficient" than normal breathing, as well as having various health benefits.

Comment: If they don't explain what thing is being optimized, that's a meaningless statement, like claiming something is "healthy" is a meaningless statement.

Comment: This link states many health benefits. https://motherhoodcommunity.com/diaphragmatic-belly-breathing/

Comment: @mathlander note that you are on a site for biology - the science for it. Our responses on here are scientifically backed and generally discount anecdotal evidence, such as almost all of that on the website you linked. I checked out their references - most of them are not scientific at all, and almost all of the actual scientific links have no mention of diaphragmatic breathing or breath control, or are very badly misinterpreted by the website authors.

Comment: @mathlander also note that your body has a natural mechanism to get you all the oxygen you need at any given time. This is highly efficient in energy terms (which is a serious evolutionary constraint) because you use minimal muscle effort to do so. I don't see that deep breathing and exerting more effort could be more efficient.

Comment: @bob1 i actually experienced benefits of deep breathing all the time myself. Tho leaving that aside, my only question is that is it in anyway harmful to deep breathe all the time scientifically?

Comment: @vipulratiya note that anecdote =! science. You may personally feel that it has helped you, which is fine and good if it works for you, but it isn't scientific. Has anyone looked at the benefits of doing it all the time - maybe. Try searching pubmed for yourself and/or ask a question about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer no, no evidence to support this at all.

Longer answer:

The adult respiratory rate is about [12-16 breaths per minute](https://www.hopkinsmedicine.org/health/conditions-and-diseases/vital-signs-body-temperature-pulse-rate-respiration-rate-blood-pressure) - this equates to about one breath per 3.75-6 seconds.

A study that I found looked at gas distribution in the lung during inspiration and breath hold found that in healthy volunteers, the lungs had approximately even distribution of gas throughout the lungs [within about 1.7 seconds](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780128036754000038)<sup>1</sup> (see fig 3.2, also reproduced below), and that this rate was more affected by posture and gravity effects on the lungs than by breathing rate. This means that even if you do slow your breathing rate and use your diaphragm more, you aren't getting more oxygen than if you breathe normally.

[image: gas distribution in lungs over time]

Reproduced from reference 1.

There are some autonomic responses to breath control, such as lowering heart-rate, but I don't know that these have any scientifically validated benefits beyond this.

1: J.M. Wild, F.C. Horn, G.J. Collier, H. Marshall,
Chapter 3 - Dynamic Imaging of Lung Ventilation and Gas Flow With Hyperpolarized Gas MRI,
Editor(s): Mitchell S. Albert, Francis T. Hane,
Hyperpolarized and Inert Gas MRI,
Academic Press,
2017,
Pages 47-59,
ISBN 9780128036754,
https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-12-803675-4.00003-8.

Comment: @mathlander what benefits did you mention? I only see your statement saying "various health benefits" without mention of what those benefits might be.

Comment: Are the benefits in the link I commented scientifically proven?

Comment: @mathlander No - see my comment about the link in the comments section for your question. Also please don't delete comments that then make subsequent comments meaningless.

Comment: I know that the link is not scientifically proven, but are the benefits given there proven anywhere else?

Comment: @mathlander may I direct you to [pubmed](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/) - if you want to know, you can first research on there and then, if needed ask specific questions about each topic. General questions don't fit well with the Stack Exchange format and questions here require prior research attempts by askers, as outlined in the [help].

Comment: https://www.passy-muir.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/51083-133296-1-PB.pdf claims lots of benefits.

Comment: @mathlander if you have a look at the object in your link you will find that it isn't Passy-Muir's, but a review from Advances in Respiratory Medicine, which is a very low ranked scientific journal from a semi-predatory publishing group; not a great publication, but credible information I suspect.